# TYPO3 argon2 password hashes matches after server move partly not

Tags: php, typo3, php-7.3, libsodium, argon

After moving a TYPO3 v9.5.10 from one server to another, some fe/be_users who have allready an argon password hash, have a login problem.
The generated hashes do not seem to match on the new server. If we reset the password within the backend to the identical password, the login works again. It concerns only a part of the users.

Does anybody have an idea what this could be due to?

PHP Versions:

- old Server 7.3.19
- new Server 7.3.17 / tested also with 7.2.30 on another server

Comment: I would expect a match or fail for all users depending on the encryption key, as this might change for another server.

Answer (score 1):

Executing a `php -i | grep sodium` in the command line interface should show something like

```
sodium
sodium support => enabled
libsodium headers version => 1.0.18
libsodium library version => 1.0.18
```

`libsodium` contains the implementation for corresponding Argon2 hashing functionality. Searching and installing `sodium` or `libsodium` in the package repositories of your operating system usually solve this.

As an alternative using PECL like shown in https://lukasmestan.com/install-libsodium-extension-in-php7/ might still work:

```
sudo pecl install -f libsodium
sudo echo "extension = sodium.so" > /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/sodium.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

The old server has the following versions installed:

```
sodium support  enabled
libsodium headers version   1.0.15
libsodium library version   1.0.15
```

the new one (Docker PHP Container) this:

```
sodium support  enabled
libsodium headers version   1.0.18
libsodium library version   1.0.18
```

Two other webservers has no sodium installed. But the problem occurs on all 3 new environments, whether with or without sodium.

Could this be a problem?
Should we check here some more?